# No rule to make .o file

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, autoconf, automake

I want to use .la library in my code.  
.la library generated from some source code.  
I want to use automake and autoconf tools to generate makefile and compile it.

my configure.ac :

> AC_INIT([Tutorial Program], 1.0)  
>  AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR(.)  
>   AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE  
>  AC_PROG_CC  
>  AC_PROG_CXX  
>  LT_INIT 
>   
>  AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)  
>  AC_OUTPUT

my Makefile.am :

> bin_PROGRAMS = aac_mhh  
>  aac_mhh_LDADD = libfdk-aac.la  
>   aac_mhhdir = .  
>  aac_mhh_HEADERS = wavreader.h  
>   aac_mhh_SOURCES = aac-enc.c wavreader.c

i use this command :

> aclocal  
>   autoconf  
>   automake --add-missing --foreign  
>   ./configure  
>   make

but my make command result is :

> make: *** No rule to make target `aac-enc.o', needed by`aac_mhh'. 
>   Stop.

Answer (score 0):

I copy a file and it Solved !! ;)